# Pro and Cons of generating Java domain classes from XML or Json schema vs writting Java classes manually

Tags: java, code-generation, auto-generate

At my work, all the Java projects so far use tools (ex: JAXB or other Json libraries) to generate Java POJOs from schemas. Can anyone tell me what the pros and cons of this approach vs writting Java domain classes by hand. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I also use JAXB at my workplace and i really find it very useful. On the very high level, the advantage of using JAXB over writing POJOs is simply what you get from an automated tool. You do not need to take the effort of doing it yourself.

I have more pros of using JAXB.

1. The output generated by it quite tight and efficient.
2. Best electronic documentation provided by JAXB download.
3. It gives integration with newer technologies like JAX-RS and JAX-WE.
4. Working on raw XML can be really tedious.
5. It comes bundled with Java6 or later versions.

Edit 1: 
CONS: I feel we can have performance level cons as compared to other similar plugins. However, CON with respect to the alternative is that we might miss out the learning the we may get by writing it ourselves. We can definitely make a good attempt for learning if system is not so complex.

Comment: thanks for your response. From what I understand is that you have to write the schemas by hand anyways right? So what is advantages of writing the schemas (either xsd or json schema) by hand and then generate the java POJO classes versus writing the POJOs at the first place by hand?